# Return specific value in string variable

Tags: string, string-parsing

I have this sample string:

"TRYU MTH INCOME=3400.00 20%INCOME=680.00 NAV MPA=439.02 OTHER MPA=580.00"

I would like to test if the label "20%INCOME" exists in this string and if it does return the corresponding dollar value (680.00) and put it into a variable.  In practice, the dollar values will change (larger and smaller) so therefore they are never in the same position within the string.  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm trying to do this in VB.NET

Comment: Please add the tag of the programming language to the question. In this case `vb.net`. You can search for tags in the "Tags" menu at the top of the page. Also, you should add what you already tried and where you got stuck.